# jquery jrating plugin extra url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I'm using a jquery plugin called jRating, it's pretty cool you can check it out here:

http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jRating

The issue I'm having is... I have multiple ratings on 1 page and thought it would be super convenient to be able to send in an extra "rating_type" parameter along with the request. Something like mypage.php?rating_type=personality. If I add it to the 'php' option, when calling

```
$(".rating").jRating({ 
... 

  phpPath: phpPath: $(this).attr("data-remote") + "?rating_type=" + $(this).attr("data-rating-type");

...
});
```

I notice the rating_type parameter is not being sent in the request.

Is there an easy way to add extra url parameters? or is this something I should just hack together myself? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple rating on your page, need to iterate the jRating in .each function and i believe that you have "data-remote" and "data-rating-type" attributes with specific values in your HTML.

Note : in jRating default php file, receiving values in $_POST, here you are passing the values in querystring, so need to use $_GET['rating_type'];

I use the example code from jRating and its working -> [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/542WZ/1/)

```
<div class="basic rating" id="12_1" data-remote="xxxx" data-rating-type="yyy" ></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.rating').each(function(index){
        $(this).jRating({
          step:true,
          length : 10, // nb of stars
          phpPath : "php/jRating.php?rating_type=thomasbabu",
          onSuccess : function(){
        alert('Success : your rate has been saved :)');
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. i don't think you need to iterate through using each because $('.rating') technically calls the jRating plugin on each $('.rating') element. i found a solution by updating the post call within the plugin itself... will post later.